# How to draw a Sequence Diagram for a Use Case that <<include>> another Use Case?

Tags: uml

i am confused in drawing a sequence diagram of a use case which includes multiple use cases, should i draw separate sequence diagram for every (included) use case or a single sequence diagram for those use cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ran into a common issue with `<<include>>` or `<<extend>>`. If any of both is used, the UC must describe the point where that actually happens. And of course you would not need to expand that part. Instead you refer to the description of I/E UCs. This can be done with diagram gates or by re-using activities.